# destructuring in clojure - embedded maps

Tags: clojure

I encountered the below destructuring in a ring handler function -

`[{{:keys [params remote]} :params :as request}]`

Its strange as this is the first time I have seen two levels of braces. Does clojure support n levels in destructuring ? I am assuming in the above the :params map is being destructured into [params remote] ?

Comment: [Binding Forms (Destructuring)](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--Binding%20Forms%20%28Destructuring%29)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Clojure supports destructuring nested data structures, although I don't know if it supports arbitrarily deep nesting. Here's a simple example of destructuring a map, where one of the two keys has a vector for its corresponding value:

```
(let [{[x y] :pos c :color}
      {:color "blue" :pos [1 2]}]
  [x y c])
```

Your example is more than that though, since it also uses the `:keys` directive, which binds a local variable with the same name as a map's keys. The following are equivalent:

```
(let [{{:keys [params remotes]} :params}
      {:params {:params "PARAMS" :remotes "REMOTES"}}]
  [remotes params])

(let [{{params :params remotes :remotes} :params}
      {:params {:params "PARAMS" :remotes "REMOTES"}}]
  [remotes params])
```

Both evaluate to `["REMOTES" "PARAMS"]`.

Comment: It supports deep nesting. Try `(def m {:hi {:hello {:wow {:amazing "steve"}}}})` then  `(let [{{{{amazing :amazing} :wow} :hello} :hi} m] amazing)`.